# Twilio-Python: Multiple Resonse Options

Tags: python-3.x, twilio, ngrok

I have managed to get the Twilio [example code](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/09/how-to-receive-and-respond-to-a-text-message-with-python-flask-and-twilio.html) for responding to an sms working.

Before I spend hours trying to figure out how to do it, is it possible to have different responses depending the incoming text message?

For example:

```py
    if request.form['Body'].lower == 'hi':
      resp.message('Hello')

    elif request.form['Body'].lower == 'bye' or 'goodbye':
      rep.message('See you later!')

    else:
      resp.message('What?')
```

Comment: You have a typo in `rep.message('See you later!')` should be `resp.message('See you later!')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Yes absolutely! This is the entire point of [Programmable SMS](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms) you get to control the response based on the incoming text, the time of day, what's in your database, or anything at all!

As Alex pointed out, you are missing an "s" in your second response in your example code. So if you tried something and it wasn't working, that's maybe why.

If you're looking to build out something conversational with SMS you may want to check out [Twilio Autopilot](https://www.twilio.com/autopilot) too. It allows you to build bots with natural language understanding, which is more powerful than just checking for equality in the message body.

Comment: My main goal is to basically be able to search a excel document through texting. Is the only way to do that through Twilio Autopilot or can I achieve that through python code?

Comment: If you’re doing things over SMS you can use whichever language you want as long as you can make and receive HTTP requests. If you want to use Twilio’s natural language understanding for it, then you might want to investigate Autopilot.